# WCF SOAP communication over wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, soap, wshttpbinding, reliablesession

I have a WCF-service hosted in IIS using a custom binding, which seems to be a wsHttpBinding with "Reliable Session" and "Transport Security" switched on. Everything works fine with the automatically generated client-code from Visual Studio.

Now I'd need to write some documentation describing the exact strings, that are exchanged. Especially for customers who are not familiar with Visual Studio or Windows at all.

Figuring out the SOAP-communication between my WCF-service and client wasn't that hard. I have added some System.Diagnostics-blocks to the clientside config-file and I get each Message logged into a file. Everything is ok so far.

Now I tried to test the service using HttpWebRequest like non-VS-customers would do, sending the SOAP-envelopes from my log. And here the trouble begins.

- First envelope I send is a CreateSequence
- I get CreateSequenceResponse from server
- I'd like to execute a specific function from the interface
- from now on the server answers with 500 - internal error

The thing is, I sent exactly the envelopes from my log, there doesn't seem to be anything in between like any ACKs or sth.

Did anyone ran into similar problems? Did I misunderstood something and is a reliable-session setting not usable with HttpWebRequest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using `HttpWebRequest` with a SOAP service?   Normally I see that in the context of REST.

Comment: Have you tried to force TLS 1.1 or 1.2?